# Flutter: Drawer and horizontal ListView on the same screen

Tags: flutter, listview, drawer

I need to create a screen that has a `ScrollView` with `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` but I also need a Drawer that can be opened by any part of the screen, but what happens is that when I create a default Drawer (`Drawer()`), it starts to overwrite the drag events causing the ListView is static.

The snippet below illustrates the problem.
https://dartpad.dev/bea0c8f1cc33cccafb8c0730e108c896

What is the correct way to implement a Drawer so that it does not 'override' the ListView that is in the body part?

Comment: that darpad link opens the default demo project. Please check the link

Comment: Sorry, now it's fixed

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?